# Way of getting queried loop before the query with a filter hook?

Tags: functions, loop, filters, php

Is there a way to get the results of a loop with a filter before the code for the loop is performed in the structure of your code?

My markup is something like this:

```
<body>
  <div>
   /* can I use a function to get the results from a loop performed after this point with a filter or hook of some sort */
  </div>
  <div>
    /* a loop/foreach etc. with results I would also like information for above */
  </div>
</body>
```

or would I need to duplicate the loop/foreach or restructure the page to achieve this?

Comment: this isn't very clear - what results do you want to get?

Comment: I have a custom post type (programme) that I'm already looping through that have a custom taxonomy (show) - the custom taxonomy (show) is used to check if another custom post type (twitter hashtag) exists, if it does I need to grab the hashtag before the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rutwick's answer was what I thought when I read the title, but I think you're just wanting to use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) which can be out of the loop like this:

```
$my_post_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'show' );
if( $my_post_terms && !is_wp_error( $my_post_terms ) ) {
    // do something here with $my_post_terms array
}
```

Comment: This is more like it but, I only want the terms from the post id's of the loop lower down the page :-s
My hack at the moment is to repeat the loop again at the top as well.
Hmm, unless I only have it at the top - the foreach should still work lower down the page I guess... need to test that...

Comment: Without seeing your full code, you can't expect any of us to give you answers specific to it. I would not guess that you had two loops based on your question. Maybe you need `rewind_posts()` to just let you run the loop twice.

Comment: resolved with your original suggestion anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pre_get_posts`. The `query` is available as a parameter to this filter. [[Codex]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/)

Comment: Not sure that will work as in some cases I'm using get_posts then iterating foreach function, or will it work for that to if I do it in a different way?

Comment: You can use it on `get_posts` as well. Just add that action right before the `get_posts` call, and remove it after the call.

Comment: And the same for WP_Query? I presume I would need to change the $query variable to my chosen variable eg if '$my_query new WP_Query' then I would need to change the variable to '$my_query' passed to the function?